# Grouping my data using python code in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like this

```
A   12  
B   15
C    9
C   12
B   15 
A   24 
B    9
C    3
A    9
```

I would like to get the output using python code as shown below

```
A   B   C
12  15  9
24  15  12
9   9   3
```

Please help to get the python code.

Comment: Yet another `pivot`, check #10 in the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(0).agg(list).to_dict()[1])
```

output:

```
    A   B   C
0   12  15  9
1   24  15  12
2   9   9   3
```

Comment: That's not really an efficient or clean way to do it. Rather go with the way of the duplicate...

Comment: @mozway I test it and `pivot` and it was faster, so I add it... :) `8.09 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop` vs `2.35 ms ± 199 µs per loop`

Comment: I tested on both a small and large dataframe and the `cumcount` way was faster, but fair enough both were quite similar (I would have expected a greater difference). Nevertheless, is too bad to have to convert to dict and again to DataFrame IMO.